# How to hide already opened panel when click on other button?

Tags: javascript

```
  <html>
<head><title></title></head>

<body>
  <div id="mySidenav1" class="sidenavlogin">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav1()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Government Departments</a>
  <a href="#">Service Agencies</a>
  <a href="#">Citizen</a>

</div>
<span class="login" onclick="openNav1()"> Login</span>

<!--api-->
<div id="mySidenav2" class="sidenavapi">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav2()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">eKYB APK</a>
  <a href="#">eKYB API</a>

</div>
<span class="api" onclick="openNav2()"> API</span>
<script>
function openNav1() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav1").style.width = "250px";
  }

function closeNav1() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav1").style.width = "0";
   }
function openNav2() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav2").style.width = "200px";
 }

function closeNav2() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav2").style.width = "0";
 }
</body>
</html>
```

in the above code when api panel is opened and when click on the login api panel should close. here i am posting the code please go through this an suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use style.display="none" instead of specifying width

Answer (score 0):

You want to use element.style.display instead of width

- element.style.display = 'block'; to show
- element.style.display = 'none'; to hide

```html
<html>
<body>
 <div id="mySidenav1" class="sidenavlogin">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav1()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Government Departments</a>
  <a href="#">Service Agencies</a>
  <a href="#">Citizen</a>
 </div>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="openNav1()">+</a>
 <span class="login" onclick="openNav1()"> Login</span>

 <!--api-->
 <div id="mySidenav2" class="sidenavapi">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav2()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">eKYB APK</a>
  <a href="#">eKYB API</a>
 </div>
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="openNav2()">+</a>
 <span class="api" onclick="openNav2()"> API</span>
 <script>
  function openNav1() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav1").style.display = "block";
  }

  function closeNav1() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav1").style.display = "none";
  }
  function openNav2() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav2").style.display = "block";
  }

  function closeNav2() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav2").style.display = "none";
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code. When you click on login, API panel closes. and when you click on API, login panel closes.

```js
function openNav1() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav1").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav1() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav1").style.display = "none";
}

function openNav2() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("mySidenav2").style.display = "block";
}

function closeNav2() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav2").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.sidenavlogin,
.sidenavapi {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav1" class="sidenavlogin">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav1()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">Government Departments</a>
  <a href="#">Service Agencies</a>
  <a href="#">Citizen</a>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="openNav1()">+</a>
<span class="login" onclick="openNav1()"> Login</span>

<!--api-->
<div id="mySidenav2" class="sidenavapi">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav2()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">eKYB APK</a>
  <a href="#">eKYB API</a>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="openNav2()">+</a>
<span class="api" onclick="openNav2()"> API</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

use common class for nav blocks.

Like `sideNav` and `style` attributes instead of setting `width`.

```
function closeAll(){  
    var divsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName("sideNav");  
    for(var i = 0; i < divsToHide.length; i++) {  
    divsToHide[i].style.display = "none";  
     //     divsToHide[i].style.width = "0"; // if purpose fully you want to use width then use this  
    }  
}  

function openNav1() {  
    closeAll();   
    document.getElementById("mySidenav1").style.display = "block";  
}
```